# Wordpress dropdown set session or cookie variable

Tags: wordpress, session, session-cookies, dropdown

I'm using a Wordpress theme that I built with some pages where there are some dropdowns (select) to choose a State of interest, then with ajax it loads some information related to the selected State. Now i need the following: when a user selects a State of interest, the site remember and automatically applies this State to all other pages where there are State dropdowns (select).

This feature will be with page reload, Content should not load in asynchronously.

Does anyone know how to do a persistence of dropdown selection throughout site?

Comment: For above scenario you can use session for dropdown variable.

Comment: @PPL Do you think can i use cokies for that?